# Device Tree Bindings For mipi-dsi - Allwinner R16 to DLPC3433

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I have a custom board that is supposed to use a MIPI-DSI video signal from the allwinner R16, that is supposed to be received by the TI DLPC3433.

[R16] >>>>>>> MIPI-DSI >>>>>>>> [DLPC3433]

Here are the datasheets:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dlpc3433.pdf?ts=1601313127857&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FDLPC3433

https://linux-sunxi.org/images/b/b3/R16_Datasheet_V1.4_%281%29.pdf

I want to properly configure the device tree. So far, I don't have a perfect indication that any video signal is being produced. What do I need to put in my device tree configuration to make it work? I am having trouble knowing exactly with documentation and examples. Where do I need to define the properties of the DLPC3433? And how would I define the properties for the DLPC3433?

Please see parts of the device tree below:

```dts
&i2c1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins_a>;
    clock-frequency = <100000>; /* i2c bus frequency 100 KHz */
    status = "okay";

    dsi_hdmi_bridge@4d {
        compatible = "ite,it6263";
        reg = <0x4d>;
        reset-gpios = <&pio 4 9 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; /* PE9 */
        
        port {
            it6263_in_dsi: endpoint {
                clock-lanes = <4>;
                data-lanes = <0 1 2 3>;
                remote-endpoint = <&dsi_out_it6263>;
            };
        };
    };
};

...

&tcon0 {
    // compatible = "allwinner,sun8i-a33-tcon";
    status = "okay";
};

&dsi {
    // compatible = "allwinner,sun6i-a31-mipi-dsi";
    status = "okay";

    ports {
        port@1 {
            reg = <1>;
            dsi_out_it6263: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&it6263_in_dsi>;
            };
        };
    };
};

&dphy {
    // compatible = "allwinner,sun6i-a31-mipi-dphy";
    status = "okay";
};
```

And here is what that device tree includes from the sun8i-a33.dtsi

```dts
dsi: dsi@1ca0000 {
    compatible = "allwinner,sun6i-a31-mipi-dsi";
    reg = <0x01ca0000 0x1000>;
    interrupts = <GIC_SPI 89 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_MIPI_DSI>,
         <&ccu CLK_DSI_SCLK>;
    clock-names = "bus", "mod";
    resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_MIPI_DSI>;
    phys = <&dphy>;
    phy-names = "dphy";
    status = "disabled";

    ports {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        port@0 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            reg = <0>;

            dsi_in_tcon0: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&tcon0_out_dsi>;
            };
        };
    };
};

dphy: d-phy@1ca1000 {
    compatible = "allwinner,sun6i-a31-mipi-dphy";
    reg = <0x01ca1000 0x1000>;
    clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_MIPI_DSI>,
         <&ccu CLK_DSI_DPHY>;
    clock-names = "bus", "mod";
    resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_MIPI_DSI>;
    status = "disabled";
    #phy-cells = <0>;
};

fe0: display-frontend@1e00000 {
    compatible = "allwinner,sun8i-a33-display-frontend";
    reg = <0x01e00000 0x20000>;
    interrupts = <GIC_SPI 93 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_DE_FE>, <&ccu CLK_DE_FE>,
         <&ccu CLK_DRAM_DE_FE>;
    clock-names = "ahb", "mod",
              "ram";
    resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_DE_FE>;

    ports {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        fe0_out: port@1 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            reg = <1>;

            fe0_out_be0: endpoint@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                remote-endpoint = <&be0_in_fe0>;
            };
        };
    };
};

be0: display-backend@1e60000 {
    compatible = "allwinner,sun8i-a33-display-backend";
    reg = <0x01e60000 0x10000>, <0x01e80000 0x1000>;
    reg-names = "be", "sat";
    interrupts = <GIC_SPI 95 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
    clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_DE_BE>, <&ccu CLK_DE_BE>,
         <&ccu CLK_DRAM_DE_BE>, <&ccu CLK_BUS_SAT>;
    clock-names = "ahb", "mod",
              "ram", "sat";
    resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_DE_BE>, <&ccu RST_BUS_SAT>;
    reset-names = "be", "sat";
    assigned-clocks = <&ccu CLK_DE_BE>;
    assigned-clock-rates = <300000000>;

    ports {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        be0_in: port@0 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            reg = <0>;

            be0_in_fe0: endpoint@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                remote-endpoint = <&fe0_out_be0>;
            };
        };

        be0_out: port@1 {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;
            reg = <1>;

            be0_out_drc0: endpoint@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                remote-endpoint = <&drc0_in_be0>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I have similar issue.